# Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name when check in documents

Tags: 2010

Hi i saw below error when spfarm user check in documents in docuemnt center web application.
Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name:  SID: 
ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance ''. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_GetProductVersions', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a known issue. Steps to resolve

1. Connect to your DB Server where you host your SharePoint configuration database.
2. Open the SQL Management studio
3. Expand the SharePoint configuration database
4. Navigate to programmability\StoredProcedures and select the stored procedure “dbo.proc_GetProductVersions”
5. Right click the stored procedure and select properties
6. Select permissions
7. On the new popup screen, click Search, select [WSS_Content_Application_Pools] database role and click OK.
8. On the first popup screen, select the role, check Execute permission and click OK.

https://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/insufficient-database-permissions-proc_getproductversions-eventid-5214/

Comment: i given permissins but again thie error appearing in uls logs